# C Program: Recursive ordering function printing incorrectly

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

I have a program to recursively order letters from a text file into a linked list in alphabetical order. I am not sure where my error is, but it currently prints the same symbol infinitely until I exit the program. I am not sure where my error might be, but I am guessing it has something to do with calling ints and chars as I am trying to print chars. Any help in determining how to properly print my program would be great.

This is what my program prints:

```
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
```

But is should be printing the text file in alphabetical order which would be:

```
abcdefghiijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list_node_alph{
    int key;
    struct list_node_alph *rest_old;
}list_node_order; 

typedef struct{
    list_node_order *the_head;
    int size;
}order_list;

list_node_order *rec_alph_order(list_node_order * old_list, int new_key);
void insert_node(order_list *the_alph, int key);
void print_alph(order_list my_list);

list_node_order *rec_alph_order(list_node_order *old_list, int new_key){
    list_node_order *new_list;
    if(old_list == NULL){
            new_list = (list_node_order *)malloc(sizeof (list_node_order));
            new_list->key = new_key;
            new_list->rest_old = NULL;
    }else if (old_list->key >= new_key){
            new_list = (list_node_order *)malloc(sizeof (list_node_order));
            new_list->key = new_key;
            new_list->rest_old = old_list;
    }else {
            new_list = old_list;
            new_list->rest_old = rec_alph_order(old_list->rest_old, new_key$
    }
    return (new_list);
}

void insert_node(order_list * the_alph, int key){
    ++(the_alph->size);
    the_alph->the_head = rec_alph_order(the_alph->the_head, key);
}
void print_alph(order_list my_list){
    printf("Pangram in alphabetical order: ");
    while(my_list->head != NULL){    //ERROR
            printf("%c", my_list->the_head);    //ERROR
    }
}
int main(void){
    int ch_count;
    int count_pangram;
    char *pang_arr;
    FILE *alph_text;
    alph_text = fopen("pangram.txt", "r");
    if(alph_text == NULL){
            printf("Empty file. \n");
    }
    order_list my_alph = {NULL, 0};
    while(( ch_count = fgetc(alph_text)) != EOF){
            putchar(ch_count);
            char next_key;
            int the_count;
            for(the_count = 0; the_count < 100; the_count++){
                    if(fscanf(alph_text, "%c", &next_key) != ' '){
                    //order_list my_alph = {NULL, 0};
                    //for(next_key; next_key != SENT; scanf("&c", &next_key$
                    insert_node(&my_alph, next_key);
                    }
            }
    }
    print_alph(my_alph);
    fclose(alph_text);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Program: Print Linked List from Recursive Ordering Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003948/c-program-print-linked-list-from-recursive-ordering-function)

Comment: Same code, just another issue after I fixed the last. Having troubles with this program. I would just like any guidance as to where I might be going wrong.

Comment: `fscanf(alph_text, "%c", &next_key) != ' '` What do you think `fscanf` returns...

Comment: And why aren't you just using `fgetc` to read a single character? And is there a reason you read them in blocks of 100?

Answer (score 0):

Please change your `void print_alph(order_list my_list);` definition as below:

```
void print_alph(order_list* my_list){
    if (my_list == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nprint_alph received NULL input");
        return;
    }
    printf("\nPangram in alphabetical order: \n");
    list_node_order* head = my_list->the_head;
    while (head != NULL){   
        printf("%c", head->key);
        head = head->rest_old;
    }
}
```

Now it should work if you call it as below from your main:

```
print_alph(&my_alph);
```

Hope this helps.

http://gk.palem.in/

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete solution.

This program is works as per your requirements.

I have used  Gopalakrishna Palem's print function here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list_node_alph{
    int key;
    struct list_node_alph *rest_old;
}list_node_order; 

typedef struct{
    list_node_order *the_head;
    int size;
}order_list;

list_node_order *rec_alph_order(list_node_order * old_list, int new_key);
void insert_node(order_list *the_alph, int key);

list_node_order *rec_alph_order(list_node_order *old_list, int new_key) {
    list_node_order *new_list;
    if(old_list == NULL){
            new_list = (list_node_order *)malloc(sizeof (list_node_order));
            new_list->key = new_key;
            new_list->rest_old = NULL;
    }else if (old_list->key >= new_key){
            new_list = (list_node_order *)malloc(sizeof (list_node_order));
            new_list->key = new_key;
            new_list->rest_old = old_list;
    }else {
            new_list = old_list;
            new_list->rest_old = rec_alph_order(old_list->rest_old, new_key);
    }
    return (new_list);
}

void insert_node(order_list * the_alph, int key){
    ++(the_alph->size);
    the_alph->the_head = rec_alph_order(the_alph->the_head, key);
}

void print_alph(order_list* my_list){
    if (my_list == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nprint_alph received NULL input");
        return;
    }
    printf("\nPangram in alphabetical order: \n");
    list_node_order* head = my_list->the_head;
    while (head != NULL){   
        printf("%c", head->key);
        head = head->rest_old;
    }
}

int main(void){
    int ch_count;
    int count_pangram;
    char *pang_arr;
    FILE *alph_text;
    alph_text = fopen("pangram.txt", "r");
    if(alph_text == NULL){
            printf("Empty file. \n");
    }
    order_list my_alph = {NULL, 0};
    while(( ch_count = fgetc(alph_text)) != EOF){
            char next_key;
            int the_count;
             printf("Inserted in array %c \n", next_key);    //ERROR
             insert_node(&my_alph, (char)ch_count);
            for(the_count = 0; the_count < 100; the_count++){
                    if(fscanf(alph_text, "%c", &next_key) > 0){
                    printf("Inserted in array %c \n", next_key);    //ERROR
                    insert_node(&my_alph, next_key);
                    }
            }
    }
    print_alph(&my_alph);
    fclose(alph_text);
    return(0);
}
```

See the changes and understand programming.!!